# How to use awk only once to yield different values

Tags: awk

I am trying to grab the password value that's quoted within

double quotes and the user name value which the last field, When i am
trying "sed RRp '/^\s*$/d' | awk -F'"'  '{print $2,  $NF}'" it takes
the second field correctly and rest takes the all output.

> File content ...

```
# cat RRp 
echo "Aj12*$" | passwd --stdin appkll 
echo "Aj12*$" | passwd --stdin horfon  
echo "Agik14#" | passwd --stdin attino
```

> Though i achieved it with below but i used awk two time, can we slim
>   it have only Once..

```
# sed '/^$/d'  RRp | awk -F'"'  '{print $2,  $NF}'| awk  '{print $1,$5}' | column -t
Aj12*$    appkll
AgkFR1!   horfon
Agik14#   attino
```

> expected output

```
Aj12*$    appkll
AgkFR1!   horfon
Agik14#   attino
```

Comment: @Ed - I have edited the Post with file content & expected output

Comment: `awk '{gsub(/"/,"",$2);print $2 "\t" $6}' file` should be close to what you have specified. Good luck.

Comment: @Karn - Can your password in column 2 contain `"` in it ? For eg. Ag"kFR# ?

Comment: @vk239 - Yes it contains .

Comment: @shellter - awk with gsub provided not fully working as its taking "|" (pipes) in between the output with the field 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'[" ]+' -v OFS='\t' '{print $2, $6}' file
Aj12*$  appkll
Aj12*$  horfon
Agik14# attino
```

or to skip blank lines and assuming column at the end:

```
awk -F'[" ]+' 'NF{print $2, $6}' file | column -t
```

Comment: this solution working fine , still i need to use `column -t` for the nicer   
output display as it suppress both blank lines and provides spaces equally between fields :-). Can you please explain the code design.

Comment: See the awk tutorial at www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html . Good luck.

Comment: The code design is absolutely fundamental awk and not much different from what you had. `man awk` if you're unsure of any part of it. awk can trivially suppress blank lines too but you didnt show any in your sample input/output in your question so you don't have that in the answer. I'll update it to skip blank lines and remove the tab OFS since you don't need it if you're piping to column.

Comment: @Ed - That's perfect , i got the synthetics of it.

Comment: We don't need `NF` if we are using `column -t` as it trims the both blank lines and places the nicer output along-with delimiting a space.

Comment: It's more efficient to remove the blank lines as they are coming into the awk script than have awk perform it's actions on them and output them for column to also then have to deal with them.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{gsub(/"/,"",$2);print $2 "\t" $6}' file
```

The above mentioned by [shellter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/620097/shellter) in the comments should work if your password is column 2 of the input file is not expected to contain `"` in it (for example `Ag"kFR#`).

If the password can contain `"` you can use `substr` to get rid of quotes in the beginning and end of column 2 as below:

```
awk '{print substr($2,2,length($2)-2) "\t" $6}' file
```

Comment: awk with gsub  and substr provided also taking "|" (pipes) in between the output with the ...like

Ag15^#e|